# Conflicts with another require in Laravel spatie package

Tags: php, laravel

I have tried to install a spatie package in my laravel project, But I got error like this

[image]

Please help how i can solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install version 5.8 of spatie sitemap by running below code

```
composer require spatie/laravel-sitemap:5.8.*
```